# What happens if you divide a uint256 by a uint88 using divU64?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, math, decimals, code

I am looking at the following function. It takes a uint256 (ercDebtSocialized) and uses safemath divU64 to divide it by a uint88. I assume this would just throw an error? I unfortunately cannot test it myself.

```
function merge(
    STypes.ShortRecord storage short,
    uint88 ercDebt,
    uint256 ercDebtSocialized,
    
) internal {
    
    short.ercDebtRate = ercDebtSocialized.divU64(short.ercDebt);
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the math library that contains divU64? As well as the contract code for the `short` function? It's hard to tell exactly what is happening without more context. For example, ercDebt could be passed to `short()` and then a `uint256` could be returned from the function, which means both parameters would be type `uint256`.